# Why last element always fired on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, error-handling, onhover

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vretc/

As you can see from the fiddle, I want to change color of span when hover on it, but somehow even I hover any in the first three element, the hover event just apply for the last span.

HTML

```
<p class="p">
    <span>Span 1</span>
</p>

<p class="p">
    <span>Span 2</span>
</p>

<p class="p">
    <span>Span 3</span>
</p>

<p class="p">
    <span>Span 4</span>
</p>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.p').each(function() {
    $span = $(this).children('span');
    $span.hover(
        function() {
            $span.css('color', 'red');
        },
        function() {
            $span.css('color', 'blue');
        }
    )
});
```

Comment: Does your actual markup has more than one span per paragraph?

Comment: Is there any reason why you wouldn't [do this with plain old css](http://jsfiddle.net/excentris/QSnNf/)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `var` before `$span`:

```
var $span = $(this).children('span');
```

Currently, you're declaring a global variable, which will be overwritten at each iteration in the loop.

**[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VREtC/5/)**

Answer (score 5):

You have only one global `$span` variable which after the loop will contain the last iterated element. Instead, make the variable local with a [`var` declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var):

```
$('.p').each(function() {
    var $span = $(this).children('span');
    $span.hover(
        function() {
            $span.css('color', 'red');
        },
        function() {
            $span.css('color', 'blue');
        }
    )
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for the `.each()`

You can try this:

```
$('.p').children('span').hover(
        function() {
            $(this).css('color', 'red');
        },
        function() {
            $(this).css('color', 'blue');
        });
```

check fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VREtC/4/)

Comment: That does a different thing.

Comment: @Bergi it changes the color of the span when you hover over it. That's what the OP wants isnt it?

Comment: OK, it's only different if there is more than one span per paragraph. Not sure whether that's intended by the OP?

Comment: @Bergi I've answered based on the information provided by the OP. Is that incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

```
$("p span").hover(function(){

  $("span ").css("color","red");
}).mouseout(function(){
$("p span ").css("color","black");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  $('.p').each(function() {
   var $span = $(this).children('span');
   $span.hover(
    function() {
        $(this).css('color', 'red');
    },
    function() {
        $(this).css('color', 'blue');
    }
  )
});
```

or without the loop  (which is not required at all )

```
 $('.p').children('span').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).css('color', 'red');
    },
    function() {
        $(this).css('color', 'blue');
    }
  )
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/VREtC/1/)

Comment: Ask @Eli why he downvotes your answer having even more wrong answer.

Comment: @Eli Haven't you reverted it?

Answer (score 0):

Please check here http://jsfiddle.net/VREtC/2/

```
  $('.p').hover(
        function() {
            $(this).css('color', 'red');
        },
        function() {
            $(this).css('color', 'blue');
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your code work, make `$span` a closure variable by using `var`

```
$('.p').each(function() {
    var $span = $(this).children('span');
    $span.hover(
        function() {
            $span.css('color', 'red');
        },
        function() {
            $span.css('color', 'blue');
        }
    )
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sf277/1/)